Python based Selenium command line scirpt
I am working on pytest [Selenium using python] and looking for below feature
In cypress we have a feature where we can store frequently used command line scripts in package.json file and use the key while execution of different
Do we have similar feature for Python ?
# package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "e2e:chrome": "cypress run --browser chrome"
  }
}

npm run e2e:chrome


I have markers as
@pytest.mark.progression
@pytest.mark.regression
..
Can any one please answer
